# How to make greenlets task come out in the right order for asynchronous I/O?

Tags: python, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, gevent

I wrote a sample code of my problem again. I have a test case where the highest time delay will be taken along with its random string.
E.g. `[1,2,7,2,1,2,8,1]` will be come `[1,2,7,7,7,7,8,8]`

It is working, however it does not come in the right order as in the output of the random strings of the 7's is random. I have used `wait()` but I am confused as to why it does not deal with the greenlet as it spawns. I have tried using `tasks = ThreadPool()` and `tasks = []`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random
import string
from gevent import sleep, spawn, wait
from gevent.threadpool import ThreadPool
import time 

def random_string():
    digits = "".join( [random.choice(string.digits) for i in xrange(8)] )
    chars = "".join( [random.choice(string.letters) for i in xrange(10)] )
    return chars

def shuffle_message (message, delay):
    sleep(delay)
    print("Shuffled message: {} and time: {}". format(message, delay))

def main():
    tasks = ThreadPool(25)
    prev = 0
    a=[1,2,7,2,1,2,8,1] #test case but it is randomise normally

    for i, elem in enumerate(a):
        delay = a[i]
        string = random_string()
        print("Message: {} and time: {}". format(string, delay))

        if prev < delay: 
            prev = delay
        else:
            delay = prev 
        print("New message: {} and time: {}". format(string, delay))
        tasks.spawn(shuffle_message, string, delay)
    wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `sleep(t)` only guarantees to sleep no shorter that `t`; it can take longer due to many factors, breaking the order.

Comment: @9000 I don't think that is the case, because if I put `sleep(0.01)` after the spawn, I will get it in the correct order every time. If it does indeed take longer, they will spawn as soon as they finished the sleep and will appear in a different order.